# Windows bat files: copying files within the bat directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

Let's say I have a folder containing my files. Inside this folder are: `copy.bat` and `files/file.txt`, `files` being another folder. How would I copy the text document to somewhere else? This main folder could be *anywhere* on my C drive. Or perhaps an external drive.

I've tried:
`ROBOCOPY ".\files\file.txt" "D:\randomfolder\file.txt"`, and the same with xcopy. Neither were able to find the original `file.txt`.

More information: The file is running as an admin, and is looking for the folder `files` within system32.

Comment: You are working with a batch file? Use `cd /d "%~dp0"` to set the working folder to the folder where your batch file is stored.

Comment: Okay, but now, it's telling me it can't access `file.txt` because the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect...?

I noticed it added a \ at the end of my path as if it was trying to read `file.txt` as a folder?

Comment: Check your syntax. You used `xcopy` syntax with `robocopy`, which has a different syntax.

Comment: If you're not changing the name of the file, you should be able to just put the folder as the destination, not the folder and filename.

Comment: @Stephan what syntax do i need?

Comment: @avery_larry Using just a folder as the destination still has the same error.

Comment: @user212205: see [robocopy/?](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: @Stephan worked. 

Time to clarify a bit more than I thought I needed to. This is an admin command prompt, and the folder I'm copying into is quite far within `Program Files/WindowsApps`. I can delete files from it fine, but ROBOCOPY says "access is denied".

Answer (score 0):

Put this into a batch file and run it. It should first set the current directory to the same directory as the batch file. Then it copies "file.txt" (which should be located in the same directory as the batch file) to "D:\randomfolder\". Then will display the text "Done!" once the copying is over.

```
@echo off
cd "%~dp0"
xcopy "file.txt" "D:\randomfolder\"
echo Done!
pause
```